# Return for an argument in iOS

Tags: ios, arguments, hook, jailbreak, theos

I'm making a cydia tweak using theos and %hooks.  One of the methods I am trying to edit is this -(void)setNumberOfCoins:(float)arg1 at the end.  I would like to know how to edit the float value and not the preceding void.  Thanks!

EDIT:  So normally the way to return a float value would be to do this

```
-(float) coinValue {
return 100;
}
```

But I would like to know how to return the argument

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you're trying to accomplish.

The method `-(void)setNumberOfCoins:(float)arg1` takes a float value and does something to it.

For example:

```
-(void)setNumberOfCoins:(float)arg1 {
    float someFloat = arg1 * 2.0f;
    float anotherFloat = arg1 * 4.0f;
    float andAnotherFloat = arg1 * 8.0f;
    NSLog(@"The value of someFloat is %f",someFloat);
    NSLog(@"The value of anotherFloat is %f",anotherFloat);
    NSLog(@"The value of andAnotherFloat is %f",andAnotherFloat);
}
```

And to use it:

```
float numCoins = 2;
[self setNumberOfCoins:numCoins];
```

Outputs:

```
The value of someFloat is 4
The value of anotherFloat is 8
The value of andAnotherFloat is 16
```

Can you be more specific?

Comment: I would like to know how you would modify the float value in a jailbreak tweak

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is call the original method with a custom argument. You can achieve it by doing this :

```
- (void)setNumberOfCoins:(float)arg1 {
    %orig(2.0); //replace 2.0 with your custom float
}
```

With the above code, the method argument will *always* be your float.